# Does the AVD Ram effects the laptop ram?

Tags: android-virtual-device, avd-manager

If I give the AVD emulator an amount of ram, does it affect my laptop?

because as default the AVD gets 2GB of ram and I would like to increase it for a better performance.

any advice about that?

Comment: Obviously, if your laptop has Y memory, and an application uses X memory, then there is only Y - X available for other applications (or cause a lot of swapping). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, this is what am trying to understand